# Нужно разделить поле в БД

Tags: c#, sql-server

не могу придумать как разделить рулон[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть есть один рулон, необходимо его разделить на несколько рулонов

Программа выполняется в WebForms C# с помощью GridView

Comment: Создать копию с половинным весом, а в текущей записи поставить половинный вес.

Comment: Если нужно одно разделить на несколько, то в терминах sql БД это будет `один-ко-многим`. Нужна таблица `ЧастиРулона` с полями `РулонId`  и `ВесЧасти`, возможно, что и Толщину и Ширину тоже в эту таблицу поместить.

Comment: @Bulson смелое утверждение, когда не знаешь предметной области.

Comment: @teran не а, достаточно осторожное утверждение помещенное в комментарий, а не в ответ на вопрос.